# override method if the class is DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using asp.net mvc4.

I am working with DLL so I have to override the classes to extend new methods.

I have a view like this:

```
@model SalesAgentLoginInfoModel
<div class="top-dropdown login">
    <div class="opener collapsed">
        <span class="login-title">@Sana.SimpleText("Account")</span>
    </div>
    <div class="summary">
        <div class="welcome border-horizontal">
            @Sana.SimpleText("Login_Welcome")
            <span class="user-name">@Model.Name</span>
        </div>
        <a href="@Url.Sana.MyAccount()" class="hyp">@Sana.SimpleText("Login_MyAccount")</a>

        <a href="@Url.Sana.RepresentCustomer()" class="hyp">@Sana.SimpleText("ButtonText_RepresentCustomer")</a>

        <a href="@Url.Sana.RepresentCustomer()" class="hyp">@Sana.SimpleText("ButtonText_baliecode")</a>
        dlkfnslkdf
        <div class="logout border-horizontal">
            <a id="logoutLink" href="@Url.Sana.Logout()" class="arrow-blue">@Sana.SimpleText("Logout_LinkText")</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the RepresentCustomer() is from this class:

```
     // Summary:
        //     The web shop URLs constructor.
        public class UrlsBuilder
        {


 public virtual string RepresentCustomer(string returnUrl = null);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the URL to the reset password page.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The reset password page URL.
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Initializes a new instance of the Sana.Commerce.Web.Routing.UrlsBuilder class.
            //
            // Parameters:
            //   routes:
            //     The route collection.
            public UrlsBuilder(RouteCollection routes);

            //
            // Summary:
            //     Gets the instance of Sana.Commerce.Web.Routing.UrlsBuilder.
            public static UrlsBuilder Current { get; }
            //
            // Summary:
            //     The routes used to construct URLs.
            public RouteCollection Routes { get; protected set; }

            //
            // Summary:
            //     Gets the URL to the add review page.
            //
            // Parameters:
            //   productId:
            //     The product ID.
            //
            //   returnUrl:
            //     The return URL.
            //
            //   navigationNodeId:
            //     The navigation node ID.
            //
            // Returns:
            //     The add review page URL.
            public virtual string AddReview(string productId, string returnUrl = null, string navigationNodeId = null);
    }
```

So I have extended the class UrlsBuilder with a new method like this:

```
 public class V_ExtendendURlsBuilder : UrlsBuilder
    {
        public V_ExtendendURlsBuilder(RouteCollection routes) : base(routes)
        {
        }

        public virtual string BaliecodeVerkoper( string url)
        {

            return url;

        }
}
```

But If I try in the view to call the new method like this:

```
 <a href="@Url.Sana...." class="hyp">@Sana.SimpleText("ButtonText_baliecode")
```

I don't see the new method BaliecodeVerkoper.

One more thing. The `public UrlsBuilder Sana { get; }`

is within this class:

```
 public class FrontendUrlHelper : SanaUrlHelper
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The facet values query string separator.
        public const string FacetValuesSeparator = "\n";

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the Sana.Commerce.Web.Frontend.FrontendUrlHelper
        //     class.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   requestContext:
        //     The request context.
        public FrontendUrlHelper(RequestContext requestContext);

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the Sana URLs builder.
        public UrlsBuilder Sana { get; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a new instance of the frontend URL helper initialized with the specified
        //     requestContext. It can be a standard helper class or a customized version if
        //     it is registered through the Sana.ObjectManager.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   requestContext:
        //     The request context.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     Returns a new instance of the frontend URL helper.
        public static FrontendUrlHelper Create(RequestContext requestContext);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Reads the selected facets from the query string of the current request.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   facets:
        //     The collection of all available facets.
        public void ReadSelectedFacets(FieldFilterCollection facets);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Sets the selected facets in the query string of the specified url.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   url:
        //     The base URL.
        //
        //   facets:
        //     The facets.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     Returns the url with the selected facets in its query string.
        public virtual string SetSelectedFacets(string url, FieldFilterCollection facets);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Reads the selected facets from the specified query string dictionary.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   queryString:
        //     The query string.
        //
        //   facets:
        //     The facets.
        protected virtual void ReadSelectedFacets(NameValueCollection queryString, FieldFilterCollection facets);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Sets the selected facets into the queryString.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   queryString:
        //     The query string dictionary.
        //
        //   facets:
        //     The facets.
        protected virtual void SetSelectedFacets(NameValueCollection queryString, FieldFilterCollection facets);
    }
```

So my question: how to extend the UrlsBuilder with the new method?

Thank you

a other try is to try it like this:

```
public class V_ExtendendURlsBuilder : UrlsBuilder
    {
        public V_ExtendendURlsBuilder(RouteCollection routes) : base(routes)
        {
        }

        public virtual string BaliecodeVerkoper( string url)
        {

            return url;

        }



    }
```

But I still don't see then the new method:

```
 public class ExtendFrontEndUrlHelper : FrontendUrlHelper
    {
        public UrlsBuilder builder;
        public ExtendFrontEndUrlHelper(RequestContext requestContext) : base(requestContext)
        {
        }

        public UrlsBuilder BalieCode()
        {

            return builder;

        }
    }
```

I just want to extend the class UrlsBuilder with a new method Baliecode. So that I can use the method in the view. But UrlsBuilder is an DLL. So I have to extend the class with a new method.

I hope I am clear now.

See my image. So I still don't see the new method Baliecode

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVoh7.jpg)

but how to use it in the view then?

```
<a href="@Url." class="hyp">@Sana.SimpleText("ButtonText_baliecode")</a>
```

@Url.. and then?? I don't see the extended...

if I go to:

```
<a href="@Url.Sana" class="hyp">@Sana.SimpleText("ButtonText_baliecode")</a>
```

and then f12 on `@Url`

I see this class:

```
public abstract class SanaWebViewPage : SanaWebViewPageBase
    {
        protected SanaWebViewPage();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the Sana view helper.
        public SanaViewHelper Sana { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the Sana.Commerce.Web.Frontend.FrontendUrlHelper object that is
        //     used to manage the URLs.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The current Sana.Commerce.Web.Frontend.FrontendUrlHelper.
        public FrontendUrlHelper Url { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the page info.
        protected virtual WebPageInfo PageInfo { get; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes the helpers.
        public override void InitHelpers();
    }
```

Oke, I have it now ,like this:

```
 public class extendedSanaWebviewPage : SanaWebViewPage
    {
        public ExtendFrontEndUrlHelper extendedFrontEndUrlHelper { get; set; }

        public override void Execute()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

But I don't see in the view: @extendedFrontEndUrlHelper

Thank you

Comment: It seems like you want a workaround to make UrlsBuilder behave as if it had BaliecodeVerkoper in it, but since UrlsBuilder is locked in a DLL you can't modify it directly.  Is that right?

Comment: yes, but you can extend the class. like in my example. And then you can add a new method. But if I do that. I still dont see the new method in the view. So yes. I try to add a new method in the UrlsBuilder  class. not directly, because it is a DLL. so I try it with a new class extended from the UrlsBuilder class

Comment: Are you able to change "public UrlsBuilder Sana { get; }" to "public V_ExtendedURLsBuilder Sana { get; }" ?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your `public UrlsBuilder Sana { get; }` is actually returning a reference to an `V_ExtendendURlsBuilder` instance, you could cast it. e.g.

```
var extendedUrlBuilder = (V_ExtendedURLsBuilder) Url.Sana;

extendedUrlBuilder.BaliecodeVerkoper("url");
```

However, it feels like perhaps a different architecture overall would be preferable.  (Casting can be clues, though not mandates, for architecture reevaluation)

EDIT: After further clarification, perhaps you want something more like:

```
public class ExtendFrontEndUrlHelper : FrontendUrlHelper
{
    V_ExtendedURLsBuilder builder;
    public ExtendFrontEndUrlHelper(RequestContext requestContext) : base(requestContext)
    {
        // presumably you assigned builder here somehow
    }

    public new V_ExtendedURLsBuilder Sana 
    { get { return builder; } }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But it seems that you don't have to cast. There has to be a other way to do it. I think so. But I don't know the correct way to do it.

Comment: I would agree casting should not be your first choice.  If you provide more details on what you're trying to accomplish, maybe we can help you better

Comment: oke, Thank you for you comment. But still how can I use the method baliecode in the view?

Comment: You'll have to ensure that @Url points to "ExtendFrontEndUrlHelper"

Comment: See this page http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx/ for how to change @Url itself

Comment: I edit the post. but can you give an example. Thank you

Comment: Yes, oke. But how can I derive ExtendFrontEndUrlHelper" from WebViewPage ? I already derive  FrontendUrlHelper. So how to do that? Thank you

Comment: So I changed the things like in the post. But in the view I still dont see the extendedFrontEndUrlHelper